# noClonflict() jQuery - Não funciona mais

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Olá, eu estava usando o noClonflict() do jQuery para não ter conflito com o site http://www.casadoboteco.com.br/

Inicialmente ele funcionou, mas depois de alguns dias está dando problema de novo.  Ele está dando conflito com as classes do lojaintegrada.

Eu não consegui de maneira nenhuma acabar com os clonflitos entre às classes.

Tentei mudar o $j para outro nome e não funcionou.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript">/script>
<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
(function ($j) {
    $j(document).ready(function () {
        $j('#cssmenu').prepend('<div id="indicatorContainer"><div id="pIndicator"><div id="cIndicator"></div></div></div>');
        var activeElement = $j('#cssmenu>ul>li:first');

        $j('#cssmenu>ul>li').each(function () {
            if ($j(this).hasClass('active')) {
                activeElement = $j(this);
            }
        });

        var posLeft = activeElement.position().left;
        var elementWidth = activeElement.width();
        posLeft = posLeft + elementWidth / 2 - 6;
        if (activeElement.hasClass('has-sub')) {
            posLeft -= 6;
        }

        $j('#cssmenu #pIndicator').css('left', posLeft);
        var element, leftPos, indicator = $j('#cssmenu pIndicator');

        $j("#cssmenu>ul>li").hover(function () {
            element = $j(this);
            var w = element.width();
            if ($j(this).hasClass('has-sub')) {
                leftPos = element.position().left + w / 2 - 12;
            } else {
                leftPos = element.position().left + w / 2 - 6;
            }

            $j('#cssmenu #pIndicator').css('left', leftPos);
        }, function () {
            $j('#cssmenu #pIndicator').css('left', posLeft);
        });

        $j('#cssmenu>ul').prepend('<li id="menu-button"><a>Menu</a></li>');
        $j("#menu-button").click(function () {
            if ($j(this).parent().hasClass('open')) {
                $j(this).parent().removeClass('open');
            } else {
                $j(this).parent().addClass('open');
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);

</script>
```

Comment: Tem algum motivo especial pra você estar usando `( function( $j ) {###} )( jQuery );` ?

Comment: Este é o código do menu, então não é de autoria minha. O problema realmente é com conflito, pois o menu funciona corretamente. O que não funciona é o mercado.

Comment: Tens outro código na página que usa o dolar (`$`)?

Comment: Difícil saber, já que a loja integrada não é open source. Eu apenas consigo colocar códigos HTML Javascript e CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta passar o `jQuery.noConflict()` para seu IIFE (e remover o `var $j = jQuery.noConflict()` do escopo global):

```
<script>
(function ($j) {

    /* código ... */

})(jQuery.noConflict());

</script>
```

Comment: Quando sobrar um tempo eu testo para ver se isto resolve.